# Complex but efficient JavaScript array filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I got a very large array of objects (persons) structured like this

```
objects = [
  {
    firstname: 'Jo',
    lastname : 'Brown'
    mail: 'jo@brown.com',
    courses: ['en', 'fr', 'es']

    ....and a lot more...
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jack',
    lastname : 'Black'
    mail: 'blackjack@jackblack.win',
    courses: ['en', 'fr']
    ....and a lot more...
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jeff',
    lastname : 'Grey'
    mail: 'grey@jeff.co.uk',
    courses: ['es']
    ....and a lot more...
  },

  ...and a lot more...
]
```

Initially I set another array which should contain filtered persons only to the main array above:

```
objectsFiltered = objects;
```

I need to build a function to filter that array with

1. a string typed into a textfield by the user of the app (search input)
2. certain other criteria selectable through links or dropdown menus ...

Therefore I store the activated filters in another array like this:

```
_objectsFilters = [
  {
    property: ['courses']
    value: ['es']
  },
  {
    property: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'mail']
    value: 'userStringInputGoesHere'
  }
]
```

In this example persons whose property `courses (Array)` contains `es` and whose property `firstname` **OR** `lastname` **OR** `mail` contain `userStringInputGoesHere` should be filtered.

I use function to get / set, reset filters like this:

```
public set objectsFilters(objectsFilters: Array<ObjectsFilters>) {
  for (let filter of objectsFilters) {
    let index = this._objectsFilters.indexOf(filter);

    /* add filter if not already active */
    if(index === -1) {
      this._objectsFilters.push(filter);
      continue;
    }

    /* remove filter if active already */
    this._objectsFilters.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

public get objectsFilters(): Array<ObjectsFilters> {
  return this._nobjectsFilter;
}
```

**Finally, the question**

Which is the best way of resetting filters and therewith the filteredObjects (persons). I thought of two ways managing this:

*Type A*

Using another function to set filtered objects (persons) *every time* the array `objectsFilters` changes. Therefore the function would always use the untouched array containing **ALL** persons (`objects`) and apply all filters. (efficiency??!)

*Type B*

If a certain filter is applied for example the first filter from above:

```
{
  property: ['courses'],
  value: ['es']
},
```

store the now filtered persons in the array `objectsFiltered` **and store the remaining persons, which are not active due to the courses filter, like this:

```
objects = [
  {
    firstname: 'Jo',
    lastname : 'Brown'
    mail: 'jo@brown.com',
    courses: ['en', 'fr', 'es']

    ....and a lot more...
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jack',
    lastname : 'Black'
    mail: 'blackjack@jackblack.win',
    courses: ['en', 'fr']
    ....and a lot more...
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jeff',
    lastname : 'Grey'
    mail: 'grey@jeff.co.uk',
    courses: ['es']
    ....and a lot more...
  },

  ...and a lot more...
]

_objectsFilters = [
  {
    property: ['courses']
    value: ['es']
  }
]

objectsFiltered = [
  {
    firstname: 'Jo',
    lastname : 'Brown'
    mail: 'jo@brown.com',
    courses: ['en', 'fr', 'es']

    ....and a lot more...
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jeff',
    lastname : 'Grey'
    mail: 'grey@jeff.co.uk',
    courses: ['es']
    ....and a lot more...
  },

  ...and a lot more...
]

inactiveObjects = [
  {
    inactiveCause: {
      property: ['courses'],
      value: ['es']
    },
    /* containing all objects inactive because of the above filter */
    objects: [
      {
        firstname: 'Jack',
        lastname : 'Black'
        mail: 'blackjack@jackblack.win',
        courses: ['en', 'fr']
        ....and a lot more...
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

This way by resetting a certain filter I could copy inactive persons back to the active persons.

Which way is the right way to go?

Comment: "Type A" sounds a lot easier to implement. Personally I'd go that route and reevaluate iif you run into performance issues. Also consider the fact that very smart people have solved these problems many times over already and someone else's widely-used, well-tested solution is almost always better than what we might write ourselves. (In other words, do it the simple way, and if you discover you need something more robust, don't reinvent the wheel.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classic case of premature optimization.

In type A, you always have the same source data, and always run one or more filters on that data.  The first filter will be the only one running against the full data set; later filters will be running against progressively smaller sets (because some of the data will already have been filtered out.)

In type B, you're modifying the source data every time a filter runs, and stashing the filtered-out elements in a separate array.  As you've described it, it won't work: if a filter changes, there's no way to know which elements need to be restored into the source array from the stash (because you can't tell which filter removed each object). The "simplest" working approach I can think of would be to keep a separate stash for each filter, so when filter X changes, you'd dump all the objects from filtered-by-X's stash back into the source and then rerun filter X.  That'd work but it'd be fairly complicated to maintain.

Code the simple method A first.  If you don't have performance problems, you're done.

If you do have performance problems, don't jump straight to method B:  instead, tweak the order in which you do the filters: if a given filter is likely to remove more data than others, do it first. If a filter is computationally expensive, do it last.

If you *still* have performance problems, then you can maybe get into the heroics involved in implementing method B. (It won't come to this.  If you're dealing with so much data clientside that you have performance issues filtering it, you already have much bigger performance issues just downloading it in the first place...)